# Не понятно поведение свойства overflow

Tags: css, css3

Есть у меня вот такой код: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y7zwcj1/20/)**

```css
  body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #fi {
   background-image: url('http://w3.wallls.com/uploads/high-thumbnail/201604/03/105003.jpg');
   width: 100%;
   height: 42rem;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #button {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   -webkit-border-radius: ;
           border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   color: silver;
   margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
   /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 165px navy; */
  }

  #sec {
   background-image: url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/FWG_2560x1440.jpg');
   width: 100%;
   height: 42rem;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
  }
  .divider {
   width: 100%;
   height: 6rem;
   background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="fi">
 <div id="button">Get Started</div>
 </div>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <div id="sec"></div>
 <div id="third"></div>
</body>
```

Если первому блоку не добавить свойтсво `overflow: hidden`, то фон этого блока (родителя) в котором находится кнопка отодвигается `margin`-ом вместе с самой кнопкой. Вобщем, уберите `overflow` и сами все увидите. Так вот, почему так происходит? Как то очень странно и непонятно ведет себя `overflow`, хотя и помог) когда учил css свойства то на примерах `overflow` казалось работает как то по другому, а тут же что то не могу понять как он работает, обьясните пожалуйста, интересно очень

Answer (score 0):

короче `margin: 100px auto 0 auto;` создает вам отступ, тк если вы убираете `overflow: hidden` у родительского элемента (который и скрывал этот самый margin) то и получается такая фигня

Comment: вот это пояснение)